# Printing data from table in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm printing all the data from one of the tables in my database using by using the `mysql_fetch_query()` to make an array and then the `while` function to print it.

The only thing is, it is skipping the first record and going straight to printing record 2. Record 1 does exist in the table, and is named as such.

Is there something I'm missing or need to add?

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$db_password")or die("cannot connect"); 

$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")or die(mysql_error()); 
$info=mysql_fetch_array($data);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Record id: <strong>" . $info['id'] . "</strong>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Visit time and date: <strong>" . $info['visitDate'] . "</strong>";    
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Previous destination: <strong>" . $info['cameFrom'] . "</strong>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Browser used: <strong>" . $info['browser'] . "</strong>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Location of user: <strong>" . $info['location'] . "</strong>";
    echo "<p> </p>";
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the first `$info=mysql_fetch_array($data);` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$info=mysql_fetch_array($data);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
```

Leave only the condition, because you make one fetch before the loop, which is the first skipper row

Answer (score 2):

remove this line before while loop:

```
$info=mysql_fetch_array($data);
```

This will fetch the first record, and when you start while loop is starts from second row because you call `mysql_fetch_array()` again.

Answer (score 0):

you have called mysql_fetch_array() two times

```
**$info=mysql_fetch_array($data);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))**
```

so your first record is already fetched with first call to mysql_fetch_array()

just remove first call and it will work ok.